# understanding python memory allocation and free up

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

I recently came across [this article](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/python-memory-management.html) about python memory allocation.

In this page it describes the memory usage of python and in there there is an example showing deepcopy of list of integers. I did the benchmark myself on Python 2.7

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4   28.051 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     5                             def function():
     6   59.098 MiB   31.047 MiB       x = list(range(1000000))  # allocate a big list
     7  107.273 MiB   48.176 MiB       y = copy.deepcopy(x)
     8   99.641 MiB   -7.633 MiB       del x
     9   99.641 MiB    0.000 MiB       return y
```

so delete x directly only removes x and all the references to integer to x right?

Doing this could not help either (So what is the difference del x and del x[:]?):

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4   28.047 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     5                             def function():
     6   59.094 MiB   31.047 MiB       x = list(range(1000000))  # allocate a big list
     7  107.270 MiB   48.176 MiB       y = copy.deepcopy(x)
     8   99.637 MiB   -7.633 MiB       del x[:]
     9   99.637 MiB    0.000 MiB       return y
```

And in contrast to deepcopy, if I use copy, after deletion seems the memory restores to previous state when x is newly created

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4   28.039 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     5                             def function():
     6   59.090 MiB   31.051 MiB       x = list(range(1000000))  # allocate a big list
     7   66.895 MiB    7.805 MiB       y = copy.copy(x)
     8   59.262 MiB   -7.633 MiB       del x[:]
     9   59.262 MiB    0.000 MiB       return y
```

For dict:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4   28.051 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     5                             def function():
     6  100.523 MiB   72.473 MiB       x = dict((e, e) for e in xrange(1000000))
     7  183.398 MiB   82.875 MiB       y = copy.deepcopy(x)
     8  135.395 MiB  -48.004 MiB       del x
     9  135.395 MiB    0.000 MiB       return y
```

And for list of lists (compare to list of integers, I assume that del x or del x[:] only removes that huge array list on heap?):

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4   28.043 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     5                             def function():
     6  107.691 MiB   79.648 MiB       x = [[] for _ in xrange(1000000)]
     7  222.312 MiB  114.621 MiB       y = copy.deepcopy(x)
     8  214.680 MiB   -7.633 MiB       del x[:]
     9  214.680 MiB    0.000 MiB       return y
```

So I want to ask:

1. So if there just no way to claim back those memory occupied by integers? Integer is an object as well right? Why memory does not get released at all? Just integer cannot be claimed? Or float and string as well? Object references as well?
2. Why there is -7 MB for memory? Is it because that the list, implemented as array list, is freed from heap?
3. whether it is a list or a dict, del x can only free the data structure itself (what i mean is that the array list structure, or dict structure), but integers, objects references can be marked as free, but not returned to system?

And how do I or if there is a way to free all the underlining lists in x in this example?

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4   28.047 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     5                             def function():
     6  248.008 MiB  219.961 MiB       x = [list(range(10)) for _ in xrange(1000000)]
     7  502.195 MiB  254.188 MiB       y = copy.deepcopy(x)
     8  494.562 MiB   -7.633 MiB       del x[:]
     9  494.562 MiB    0.000 MiB       return y
```

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

`del` does not free variables as in C, it simply says that you no longer need it. What then happens is an implementation detail.

### Rationalle

So what is happening here is that [`del`](https://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) does *not* free memory, it simply tells python that you are done with the variable. Specifically:

> 7.5. The del statement
>
> del_stmt ::=  “del” target_list
>
> Deletion is recursively defined very similar to the way assignment is defined. Rather than spelling it out in full details, here are some hints.
>
> Deletion of a target list recursively deletes each target, from left to right.
>
> **Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace**, depending on whether the name occurs in a global statement in the same code block. If the name is unbound, a NameError exception will be raised.
>
> Deletion of attribute references, subscriptions and slicings is passed to the primary object involved; deletion of a slicing is in general equivalent to assignment of an empty slice of the right type (but even this is determined by the sliced object).

Note that there is no mention of freeing memory. What instead happens is that you tell python that it can do "whatever it wants" with that memory. In this case your python implementation (which I assume is CPython) stores the memory for later use in a memory cache. This allows python to run faster by not needing to allocate as much memory later.

### Example

Consider this example, where we `del x` and then create a copy of `y` again. Note that the amount of memory allocated during the second copy is smaller than during the first. This is because memory is re-used. If we do this again, we see that hardly any memory at all is allocated during the third copy, because python is simply re-using previously allocated memory:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4   34.777 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
     5                             def function():
     6   37.504 MiB    2.727 MiB       x = [list(range(10)) for _ in xrange(10000)]
     7   40.773 MiB    3.270 MiB       y = copy.deepcopy(x)
     8   40.773 MiB    0.000 MiB       del x
     9   41.820 MiB    1.047 MiB       y2 = copy.deepcopy(y)
    10   41.820 MiB    0.000 MiB       del y2
    11   41.824 MiB    0.004 MiB       y3 = copy.deepcopy(y)
    12   41.824 MiB    0.000 MiB       return y
```

### Sources

Excellent "blog": http://www.evanjones.ca/memoryallocator/

http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm